# Translate element to top of page

Tags: html, css, translate-animation, keyframe

I'm trying to translate an element on my webpage to the top of the page. I can get it to move x amount of pixels up, but with different screen sizes, that won't scale correctly, hence, I am looking for a more relative solution.

What I have so far is:

```
body {
-webkit-animation-name: raiseBody;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.7s;
}
@keyframes raiseBody {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -300px);
}
```

but like I said before, this doesn't work on phones and such because it doesn't scale correctly. I've been stuck on this for a few hours so any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: You would need to use absolute positioning...not translation....and probably javascript depending on what you are trying to achieve. Also, I'm not sure you can reallistically translate the `body` element...that seems an odd choice.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've set up each element that I want to translate with absolute positioning, but I still can't figure out how to translate them to the top of the page